# Wordpress Database Output - Remove SQL Injection Escapes

Tags: sql, wordpress, sql-injection

I'm having a problem using $wbdb. When I insert or update data using $wpdb->insert or $wpdb->update, the SQL injection protection actually inserts the \' into the database, and when outputting that information it has the SQL escape with it.  (ie: My Value\'s Escaped).

I know there's gotta be a way to escape this using a wordpress function, but I haven't been able to find it searching google and the wordpress codex.  ...So what's that function, or what am I doing wrong (seems like the '\' shouldn't really get to the database in the first place)  Thanks!

Comment: So is there a solution for these magic quotes?

Comment: I know this was created years ago, but was an actual solution ever found for this that didn't involve disabling magicquotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if [`magic_quotes`](https://www.php.net/magic_quotes) are enabled on the server you are using.

There are a number of SO questions and answers that deal with what they are, why they're bad, and how to get rid of them, so I won't explicitly explain here, but suggest you look at a few of the following:

- [Magic quotes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220437/magic-quotes-in-php)
- [Work around magic quotes, or just make sure they're off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370292/work-around-magic-quotes-or-just-make-sure-theyre-off)
- [How can I disable PHP magic quotes at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153741/how-can-i-disable-php-magic-quotes-at-runtime)
- [How to turn off magic quotes on shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517008/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-on-shared-hosting)
- [PHP protecting itself from SQL injections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648307/php-protecting-itself-from-sql-injections)