# $wpdb->update or $wpdb->insert results in slashes being added in front of quotes

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This question has been posed a few times in various places, but I haven't found a definative and clear answer. Most solutions involve people saying to disable Magic Quotes on the php.ini file (which I did) or modifying core WP files.

Anyways, the question is this: why is it everytime I use $wpdb->insert or $wpdb->update a slash gets added before any single quote. So for instance:

> **I've eaten strawberries** becomes **I\'ve eaten strawberries**

Here's a sample code I used:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$wpdb->update('table_name', array('id'=>$id, 'title'=>$title, 'message'=>$message), array('id'=>$id))
```

The same problem was here: [Wordpress Database Output - Remove SQL Injection Escapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739875/wordpress-database-output-remove-sql-injection-escapes) but it was never solved aside from "disable magic quotes"

Comment: Are you sure you have magic quotes disabled? Have you checked it in `phpinfo()`

Comment: Yea, here's the excerpt from phpinfo -->

magic_quotes_gpc Off Off
magic_quotes_runtime Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off

Comment: Are those extra / missing quotes in the `update()` call typos or actually in your code?

Comment: @phil the extra quotes are being added, no typos here. Take a look at the strawberry example to see what it does. It's something to do with the wpdb->insert and wpdb->update actually putting a slash in front, but I have no clue how to disable it doing that

Comment: @fewpeople Perhaps you misunderstood. The last line of code in your question is a mess of misplaced single-quotes. Is that what it actually looks like? Also, where are you seeing the added slashes (ie, in echo'd markup, phpMyAdmin, MySQL console, etc)?

Comment: @phil the code in the explaination was wrong, see revised edit. I'm seeing the added slashes in phpMyadmin...so it's storing the data with slashes in the dB

Answer (score 71, accepted):

After spending the day on this, the answer is as follows:

Wordpress escapes at the $_POST declaration, not at the actual insert, which is bizarre.

```
$id = stripslashes_deep($_POST['id']); //added stripslashes_deep which removes WP escaping.
$title = stripslashes_deep($_POST['title']);
$message = stripslashes_deep($_POST['message']);

$wpdb->update('table_name', array('id'=>$id, 'title'=>$title, 'message'=>$message), array('id'=>$id));
```

Doing this will mean that WP will not add slashes before any quotes.

Comment: Life saver. Thanks @J Lee. This would have definitely taken some time to debug if this wasn't here.

Comment: You can also use `wp_unslash()` on the whole `$_POST` array

Answer (score 7):

a little more info--WordPress decided to make people think they were going crazy by adding 'magic quotes' even if you've got it turned off starting in version 3.0. Any access to $_REQUEST, $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, or $_SERVER will be affected. See `wp-includes/load.php`.

```
 /* Add magic quotes to $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, and $_SERVER.
 * @since 3.0.0
 */
function wp_magic_quotes() {
        // If already slashed, strip.
        if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
                $_GET    = stripslashes_deep( $_GET    );
                $_POST   = stripslashes_deep( $_POST   );
                $_COOKIE = stripslashes_deep( $_COOKIE );
        }

        // Escape with wpdb.
        $_GET    = add_magic_quotes( $_GET    );
        $_POST   = add_magic_quotes( $_POST   );
        $_COOKIE = add_magic_quotes( $_COOKIE );
        $_SERVER = add_magic_quotes( $_SERVER );

        // Force REQUEST to be GET + POST.
        $_REQUEST = array_merge( $_GET, $_POST );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> WordPress ignores the built in php magic quotes setting and the value
>   of get_magic_quotes_gpc() and will always add magic quotes (even after
>   the feature is removed from PHP in 5.4).

you can use this instead

```
//replace $_POST with $POST
$POST      = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
$wpdb->insert( 
        'wp_mytable', 
        array( 
            'field_name'        => $POST['field_name'], 
            'type'              => $POST['type'],
            'values'            => serialize($POST['values']),
            'unanswered_link'   => $POST['unanswered_link'], 
        ), 
        array( 
            '%s','%s','%s','%s'
        ) 
    );
```

> WordPress does this because too much core and plugin code has come to
>   rely on the quotes being there, so disabling quotes on the super
>   globals (as is done in both the "Basic Example" and "Good Coding
>   Practice" examples above) is likely to cause security holes.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep

Comment: Interestingly enough, you can also replace the entire $_POST variable itself (instead of creating a new variable without the underscore).  Not sure how advisable that is...